# How to invert colors of a picture on Mac?

Tags: color, color-conversion, mac

**How to invert colors of a picture on Mac?**

I'm using macOS 10.13.

Comment: Using what tools? have you tried looking into other questions here? I'm sure someone must have asked before, but you have to at least specify what software are you / will you use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Absent photo manipulation software (such as Photoshop, GIMP, Affinity Photo, PixelMator, Luminar) on a Mac you can use the inbuilt OS application called Preview for a lot of basic image manipulation stuff, and even the Photos app has a ton of tone-mapping and histogram editing you can do - but I don't recall there being a simple inversion filter or tool there. However, I know that in the Quartz filters built into the OS core graphics there definitely is such a tool, and I think you can still easily access those tools with the Colour Profiler Utility.

You might also look into Automator, which definitely allows access to that sort of thing absent specific software.

But to be clear - absent the kinds of tools we here at **GD.SE** use routinely and are expert in, this question becomes less appropriate for us, as we're graphic designers here - you might consider moving this question to [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions] if you're insisting on doing this with ***only*** the tools natively available in the Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the image in **Mac Preview**

[image]

- Go to menu Tools → Color Adjustment
- Change the histogram extreme sliders position: move the shadow slider to the right and the light slider to the left

[image]

- Menu File → Save